# How to include commit number in description/environment when deploying a cloud function?

Tags: python, git, google-cloud-functions

We can [deploy](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploying) Google Cloud functions as follows:

```
gcloud functions deploy NAME --entry-point NAME --runtime RUNTIME TRIGGER [FLAGS...]
```

Now, I would like to better keep track of which commit I am in when deploying.

Is there a way to automatically fetch the current branch + latest commit number (e.g. `e5de21d`) and attach it to the deployment?

Comment: `git rev-parse HEAD` should give you the current commit hash, `git branch --show-current` will give you the current branch

Answer (score 1):

You could probably [set](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/deploy#--update-labels) this data as [labels](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-labels) in order to keep track of them

For instance you could assign these 2 labels to a particular function

```
branch:master
commit:e5de21d
```